# Pyqt4 - add values of 2 combo boxes into a textEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, concatenation

I need help to add values of 2 combo boxes into a same `QTextEdit`. This is part of my code:

```
    self.pushButton2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
    self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 950, 98, 27))
    self.pushButton2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8('botao2'))
    self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
    self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(920, 850, 111, 27))
    self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox_2 = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
    self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(920, 950, 78, 27))
    self.comboBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox_2"))
    self.comboBox_2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox_2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox_2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.text2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
    self.text2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250,700, 500, 200))
    self.text2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.comboBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("activated(QString)")), self.text2.append)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.comboBox_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("activated(QString)")), self.text2.append)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
self.comboBox.setItemText(0, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Narrador", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(1, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Filme", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(2, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Ator", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
self.comboBox.setItemText(3, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Genero", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "-1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "0", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

I need to show in the **same** line of a `QTextEdit` (my text2), the values of this combo boxes, for example:

> combobox = I selected "Genero"
>   combobox_2 = I selected "0"

When I press a simple button I want to show in the same line of my text2: "Genero,0".

How i can do it? Do i need to concatenate these combo boxes? How i can do it?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a slot for the signal `clicked` of the `QPushButton` that adds a line to your `QTextEdit` with the values of your `QComboxBox`es, something like this:

```
    self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton2_clicked)

def on_pushButton2_clicked(self):
    text1 = self.comboBox_1.currentText()
    text2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
    self.text2.append("{0},{1}".format(text1, text2))
```

Comment: `self.text2.append("{0},{1}".format(text, text2))` is for python 3.x but for previous versions of python this should be replaced with `self.text2.append("%s,%s"(text1, text2))`

Comment: @PBLNarasimhaRao That is incorrect... and in any case it would be `"%s,%s" % (text1, text2)`

Comment: i mean to say `.format` is not supported in previous versions of Python 3.x

Comment: @PBLNarasimhaRao it is supported *at least* from 2.7, which is the version i'm using, since 2.6 to be more exact.

Comment: First, thanks guys.
And how i can do it for a list? i think its better using a listwidget.. i want to set the values of the  combo boxes to the same line of a list, its possible to do? i think it because later i will need pass it to a axel table...

Comment: @MarcoBochernitsan I can help you with that, could you mark this post as accepted and create another one with that question? And please mention me in a comment so I get notified